# ruby script to error trap when importing XML files into an sql server DB

Tags: ruby, sql-server, windows-server

I am using a rb file to create and download XML files from a postgresql DB from heroku onto our local Windows server. I
A SQL script called from within the ruby script then migrates the XML into a sql server DB. 
Then another script is called to migrate some of the data into another SQL Server DB.
Is there a way to catch errors if the XML to sql server migration is not correct?

thanks
maggs

Comment: There is. Any further answer would depend on what exactly you are doing, with which tools, and which kinds of errors you are anticipating. `rescue` and `if` probably figure prominently.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please reread your question and pretend like someone asked you the same question, and see if there is enough information for you to diagnose the problem and answer it. As is, it's way too broad and ill-defined. We need detail about what you're doing, including showing the minimal code necessary to demonstrate what you're doing. Without that we can't do much better than answer "yes".

Comment: Hi I was looking for some general tips and maybe some good resources to look at. thanks